# How to organise your strings for large projects

Tags: android

I'm making an android app for my school project at it seems like its going to have a lot of things (like strings) but I've only seen people use one res/string.xml file. Is there a way to organize and categorize the strings I'm going to use for each activity? I don't want the string.xml file to become too big that it will be difficult for me to locate string resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have several files for strings as you want. You just have to put each file in : res/values/filename.xml
You can find more in the documentation : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String